# Use jquery show() and animate() together?

Tags: jquery

I have an issue getting jquery animate to fire after calling show or fadeIn on a hidden absolutely positioned div (display = none).  The fadeIn/Show works fine, but the animate does nothing - and the logic function definitely evaluates to true after testing.  I'm using IE9.  Am I missing something??  Thanks.

```
function checkscroll(x) {

    $("#" + x).fadeIn(100);
    var t = $(window).height();
    var m = $("#" + x).offset();
    var p = m.top;
    var x = $("#" + x).height();

    if ((p + x) > t) {
        $("#" + x).animate({ marginBottom: "20px"}, "fast");

    }
}
```

Comment: It appears you are using the variable 'x' twice, first to fadein, but later you change it to resemble the height, maybe thats the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After writing `var x = $("#" + x).height();`, `x` becomes a number, not an element ID.
Therefore, `$("#" + x)` doesn't match anything.

You should use longer, more descriptive variable names.

Comment: ah. my bad.  thanks for that - got it working now after using getelementbyid on the # + x variable and replacing all the other varaiables.  thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You're recreating the x variable, try using another variable instead.

Try this:

```
function checkscroll(id) {
    $("#" + id).fadeIn(100);
    var t = $(window).height();
    var m = $("#" + id).offset();
    var p = m.top;
    var x = $("#" + id).height();

    if ((p + x) > t) {
        $("#" + id).animate({ marginBottom: "20px"}, "fast");

    }
}
```